# Is it possible to replace Integer[] with int[]?

Tags: java, integer, int

I'm trying to rewrite my code for a little bit. Is it possible to use `int[]` array instead of `Integer[]` in my code?

When I replacing all of `Integer[]` with `int[]`, I'm stuck in part of replacing:

```java
.toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

with

```java
.toArray(int[]::new);
```

```java
public class Main {

    private static final int MODULO = (int) (Math.pow(10, 9) + 7);

    private static int modulate(final long result) {
        return (int) (result % MODULO);
    }

    //private static

    private static Integer[] steps(final int smaller, final int larger) {
        final int lcm = lowestCommonMultiple(smaller, larger);
        final int max = lcm / smaller;
        final int min = lcm / larger;
        final Integer[] result = new Integer[max * 2];

        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            result[pos++] = (i * smaller);
            if (i <= min) {
                result[pos++] = (i * larger);
            }
        }
        return Arrays.stream(result)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .sorted()
                .distinct()
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    private static long nthNonZeroMagicalNumber(final int N, final int smaller, final int larger) {
        final Integer[] stepsInCycle = steps(smaller, larger);
        final long lcm = stepsInCycle[stepsInCycle.length - 1];
        final int inOneCycle = stepsInCycle.length;
        final int fullCycleCount = N / inOneCycle;
        int count = fullCycleCount * inOneCycle;
        final long evaluated = fullCycleCount * lcm;
        if (count == N) {
            return evaluated;
        }
        final int remainder = N - count - 1;
        return stepsInCycle[remainder] + evaluated;
    }

    private static int greatestCommonDenominator(int a, int b) {
        while (b > 0) {
            int temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int lowestCommonMultiple(final int a, final int b) {
        return a * (b / greatestCommonDenominator(a, b));
    }

    public static int nthMagicalNumber(final int N, final int A, final int B) {
        if (N == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (A == B) {
            final long result = (long) A * (long) N;
            return modulate(result);
        } else if (N == 1) {
            return modulate(Math.min(A, B));
        }
        return modulate(nthNonZeroMagicalNumber(N, Math.min(A, B), Math.max(A, B)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = nthMagicalNumber(53776, 22434, 31343);

    }
}
```

If someone can give me any advice I will really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @burm87 Arrays are objects, even if their elements are primitives. You use `new` to construct objects. `IntFunction<int[]> i = int[]::new;` is perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you start with an `Integer[]`, you can unbox the Integers inside the stream, which will give an `IntStream` from your `Stream<Integer>`.

```
// if result is an Integer[]
return Arrays.stream(result)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .sorted()
        .distinct()
        .mapToInt(n -> n) // this gives an IntStream
        .toArray();       // this returns an int[]
```

If you actually change your `result` array to type `int[]` then you won't need the unboxing, but you won't be able to filter out elements using `nonNull` any more: the unwritten elements in your array will be zero instead of null. So you would have:

```
// if result is an int[]
return Arrays.stream(result)
             .filter(n -> n!=0)
             .sorted()
             .distinct()
             .toArray();
```

You might be better off using lists instead of arrays. A list can increase in size as required, so you don't have to track what position you have reached, or exclude elements you haven't written to.

Comment: The `.mapToInt(n -> n)` is unnecessary if you've changed the source array to an `int[]` as well (question implies that they have)

Comment: @JonK The fact that their starting array might contain null (which the stream filters out) suggests that it must be `Integer[]`, not `int[]`.

Comment: In this instance I suspect it's overly defensive programming on the OP's part - I can't see a way for any of those elements to actually be `null` based on the code that's been posted

Comment: Or he/she could just start with an array of ```int[]```

Comment: @JonK You are incorrect. The `result` array inside the method is oversized, and will indeed have null elements.

Comment: That's true when the source array is an `Integer[]`, but not when it's an `int[]`. The OP has stated that they're replacing all `Integer[]`s with `int[]`